# If prime gaps grow polynomially, would this algorithm to find $n$ amount of primes be pseudo-polynomial?

Tags: algorithms

I know the answer, yes, but I'm really not sure if prime-gaps grow exponentially.

Consider the prime-gap between $2$ and $3$. It's just a small gap of $1$. The gaps grow larger with bigger magnitudes given for input.

```
s = 10
m = 0
primes = []
while length(primes) < s:
    m = m + 1
    if AKS.isprime(m) == True:
        primes.append(m)

OUTPUT(primes)
```

**Output**

```
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29]
```

My question is, *Do these gaps grow exponentially?*

Comment: Prime gaps grow _logarithmically_, on average. But only on average -- they can dance around in a most undignified manner.

Comment: @TonK On worst case do they still grow slower than $2$^$n$?

Comment: Have a look at this for approximations of the prime counting function: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime-counting_function